# How to Open registry folder in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\google");
    }
}
```

`form1` has only ONE Button.

I want to open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\google\` by clicking the button.

But the Button does nothing after clicking, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code opens an object and returns it. If you assign this object to a variable like this:

`var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\google");`

you can for example, change it after that assignment.

If you want to open regedit tool, you should use following code:

`Process.Start("regedit.exe")`

Comment: I edit the code to be like this


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\google");
            
            Process.Start("regedit.exe");
        }
the registry tool Open , But not the folder google ,
i think the process.start should take tow parameters
is that rigth ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. Even if you do something with the value that you retrieve from the function, it will not work for a simple reason:

When you do:

`Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\google");`

you are opening a subkey of the current user key, and you are searching for another current user within the current user; meaning that you are actually searching for:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\google`

what you need to do is search for: `@"software\google"`

eg:

```
MessageBox.Show(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"software\google").ToString());
```

2. You are misunderstanding the meaning of "open"; open doesn't mean that it will open the registry editor window, it just means that behind the scenes, your app will open the key for further use.

If I understand you correctly, you want the registry editor window to open up, and navigate automatically to the Google key.

For that, you can do the following trick:

Set the regedit's **LastKey** key to the Google path, and then once you open regedit it will navigate there automatically:

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit", true);
if (myKey != null)
{
    myKey.SetValue("LastKey", @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\google", RegistryValueKind.String);
    myKey.Close();
}
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("regedit.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks , Now I know my wrong
it's was in ""HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\"
thank's a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In programming in general there are two types of functions:

Functions with side effects which actually **do** something, and functions without side effects which **return** something.

In your case `OpenSubKey` returns a `RegistryKey`. You have to do something with it, otherwise your button press has no effect.

And the reason is, that your function call has no side effects.